# Hibernate configuration throws CacheException - No Cache configured

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm looking through some legacy code trying to get everything to build and am running into an issue.

When I run a unit test and startup a Hibernate configuration I get the error:

> net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from null. Initial
>   cause was null

However, in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file I've specified

```
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
```

So, why is it even looking for an EhCache?

I've noticed that in Hibernate's `SessionFactoryImpl` class there's a

```
settings.getCacheProvider().start(this.properties);
```

which is having problems because `this.properties` is null. But, isn't this accounted for by what I have in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?

Comment: Are you sure your config file is used when running a test environment? You may need to add a separate config for running the tests, depending on what kind of project you have (i.e. maven or something else).

Comment: Good catch! It turns out that I'm using a mock of another class. Trying to locate its config so that I can turn off the cache.